# Can't release object

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I can't release this object and I don't know why:

```
SchedVO *tmpSched;
tmpSched = [SchedVO alloc];
NSString *timeStr;
timeStr = [[node attributeForName:@"timestamp"] stringValue];
tmpSched.date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeStr.intValue];
tmpSched.uid = [node stringValue];
[playListArr addObject:tmpSched];
[tmpSched release];
```

sched:

```
@interface SchedVO : NSObject 
{
    NSDate      *date;
    NSString    *uid;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *uid;


@end
```

I think its somehow the `nsdate` part. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're missing an `init`.  `tmpSched = [[SchedVO alloc] init];`  Init increments the Retain count to 1.  You can't release something that hasn't been initialized.